# How can I use get to return a boolean from a C# class?

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
public class Content {
   public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
   public string RowKey { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class ContentViewModel
    {
        public string RowKey { get; set; }
        public Content Content { get; set; }
        public Boolean UseRowKey { }

    }
```

Can someone tell me how I can code in for UseRowKey to be read only and for it to return true if the Content.RowKey first character is "X".

Comment: Please read a bit about properties and string manipulation on MSDN so you can better understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use get to return a boolean from a C# class?

You can not because classes have no return value, only methods have (and properties - the get method is a special case of method).

Now:

> Can someone tell me how I can code in for UseRowKey to be read only and for it to return 
>   true if the Content.RowKey first character is "X"

But that is NOT "returning boolean from a class", you know.

```
public bool UseRowKey { get { return RowKey.StartsWith("X"); }}
```

(untested, you may have to debug)

Read only: do not provide a set.
First char X: programming.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code:

```
public Boolean UseRowKey {
    get {
        return Content != null
            && Content.RowKey != null
            && Content.RowKey.Length > 0
            && Content.RowKey[0] == 'X';
    }
}
```

You can remove some of these checks if your constructors and setters verify that these conditions are always false. For example, if you set content in the constructor and add a check to the setter to trap null assignments of `Content`, you could remove the `Content != null` part.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The efficiency of the two should be the same, so it's a matter of personal preference. I often use `!=` myself, but I find `>` a lot more common.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Boolean UseRowKey 
{  
   get
   {
       if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(RowKey))
       {
           return RowKey[0] == 'X'; 
       }
       return false;

   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool UseRowkey
{
    get
    {
        return this.Content.RowKey[0] == 'X';
    }
}
```

By the way, it seems youre doing ViewModel pattern wrong. ViewModel should not be a wrapper of a Model. The values of Model should be mapped to ViewModel by some external code. For example, using AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

And yet another option... this one accepts both upper-case `X` and lower-case `x`.

```
public bool UseRowKey
{
    get
    {
        return Content != null
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Content.RowKey)
            && Content.RowKey
            .StartsWith("x", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```